# yum install failed with baserepo not found

Tags: centos, yum

I want to install `nfs-utils`. It fails with the below statement:

```
cannot find a valid basurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Then I ping "mirror.hostduplex.com" and "mirror.centos.org" and it passed.
I tried google.com with success, meaning I have a network connection.

But `curl` to any of the URLs above fails. See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>Authentication failed</title>
<style type="text/css"> body{ font-family-verdana; font-size: 8pt; line-height: 11pt;} </style>
</head><body>
<a id="redirect" href="https://networkregistration.regus.com/Regusintelligentnetwork.aspx?DEVICE=0133&USER=00-1e-c9-5b-ac-09&URL=google.com">Click Here</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tc = document.getElementById("redirect");
if (tc) window.location =tc.href;   
</script>
</body></html>
```

Any suggestions on how to install `nfs-utils`?

Comment: What are the contents of the [base] stanza of /etc/yum/repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo?